# Update programming on a PIC microcontroller without other external hardware?

Tags: usb, pic, firmware

I'm having a friend that is an electronics engineer plan and build some PCBs for myself and several friends, for use in an automotive environment. One major goal of this project is to allow the PIC microcontrollers to have the programming updated, without the use of additional external hardware, such as a PICkit or anything along those lines. I would love for us to be able to simply connect the PCB to a laptop or desktop via USB, and simply write updated programming to the controller, just like how an Arduino works.

We are currently looking at a PIC24F08KM204 for the project. Does anyone know how my goal can be accomplished, if it is possible? I don't mind adding some more components to the PCBs, at a reasonable cost, to avoid the need of an external piece of third-party hardware to update the controller as we tweak settings. Is there perhaps another controller line I should be looking at that offers this ability?

I'm not very familiar with a lot of the terms used in this environment, so if anyone that is willing to help wouldn't mind making their response dummy-proof I'd really appreciate it :) :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to implement is called a bootloader. For PIC24, start here -> http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=Microchip%20Easy%20Bootloader . If you don't need USB for anything else, use serial port plus USB-to-serial converter chip.

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg. We are going to look at that as a solution, I really appreciate your help!!!!!